# Connect wifi adapter to motherboard ethernet connection, same machine, linux

Tags: wifi, ethernet, bridge, internet

I just want to connect my wifi adapter to my ethernet adapter, plug the ethernet adapter (onboard) into a router, and share Internet with the wifi adapter through the router. Possible? Easy? I'm using networkmanager gnome on debian bullseye.

Comment: What kind of wifi "adapter" are we talking about?

Comment: One that fits in a pcie slot.

Comment: If your Debian system acts as Access Point, yes it's possible, though I don't know if NetworkManager knows how to do this. Is that the case: is it the AP? Maybe a schematic explaining what you intend would help (because if the Access Point is elsewhere, then better forget about it).

Comment: I'll see if I can do it like that.